# PyQt 5 Hiding and showing widgets an dealing with List Widgets

Tags: pyqt5

I am pretty new to Python and very new to PyQt.  Just trying to find a solution on how to hide widgets that do not need to be shown until a button is clicked.  Also can't figure out the syntax with items in a list widget.  If x is clicked in a list widget it will execute y.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share with us code or anything that can indicate the specific problem you are facing and what you have tried.

Comment: I am using QT Designer and this is the code I am using to hide frames that I have made and show one of the many frames that I want to see when a button is clicked.  With my limited knowledge only way I know how to make this work is to show() and hide() everything else with the signal/slot editor on clicked().  self.alexaSxtButton.clicked.connect(self.statsAlexaSxtframe.show)
        self.alexaSxtButton.clicked.connect(self.statsAlexaMiniframe.hide)

Comment: @AxelFoley In SO for this type of problems, a [mcve] is required, and I recommend reading [ask] and passing the [tour] so that you know more about the good practices of the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a slot when clicking items in QListWidget,
you can use **itemClicked** signal to accomplish it,

Hear is an example,

```
class YourListWidget(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(YourListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.do_something)

    def do_something(self, item):
        # item is the item you clicked, it is a QListWidgetItem object
        # you can see its name by calling text() method of QListWidgetItem,
        # or do anything you want in this slot.
        print(item.text())
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I ended up using a lambda.